# Changing Dativ-prepositions to Genitiv-prepositions: e.g. "zugunsten mir" with Genitiv instead of Dativ

Tags: preposition, genitive, dative

The preposition *zugunsten* is used both with dative and genitive. If I remember well, that's the same case for *wegen*. With *wegen*, in written language, is better *meinetwegen* as *wegen mir*, that is `Genitiv` is prefered over `Dativ`.

Which would be the genitive version of

> mir zugunsten *oder* zugunsten mir ?

In case there is a fixed expression, which would be the generalization to other  (not so often used) dual genitive-dative-prepositions?

Comment: what about *zugunsten meiner*?

Comment: @bummi So, z.B. *Zugunsten meiner fällt der Termin aus*? Klingt es nicht seltsam?

Comment: doch absolut, *zugunsten meiner Person ...* ist aber bisweilen zu lesen/hören.

Comment: zu meinen Gunsten

Comment: Ich sage auch `wegen meiner`, wenn mir danach ist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `zugunsten` treated the first person pronouns the same way `wegen` did, it would be `zumeinergunsten`. But it doesn't. `zugunsten` is a concentrated form of the older `zu Gunsten`. That's why, in connection with the first person pronouns it becomes

> zu meinen Gunsten

Answer (score 3):

Actually, *wegen* and *zugunsten* are quite dissimilar. The case of the phrase governed by *wegen* varies between genitive and dative (*wegen des Wetters*, *wegen dem Wetter*) depending on whether it is elaborated or colloquial speech, on the preferences and education of the speaker, etc.; additionally, the postposition can only govern genitive (*des Wetters wegen*). For *zugunsten*, however, it only depends on its usage as a preposition or a postposition. The preposition governs genitive, the postposition dative:

> Sie haben zugunsten ihres Vaters darauf verzichtet.
>   Sie haben ihrem Vater zugunsten darauf verzichtet.

I would say that the postpositional use is less common.

For your specific question, this means that either *mir zugunsten* or *zugunsten meiner* are conceivable; *zugunsten mir* is ungrammatical. The genitive of personal pronouns sounds awkward, though, and is almost always avoided in present-day German. As already mentioned by Carsten Schulz and Toscho, one common choice is to undo the grammaticalization of *zugunsten*, which is a contraction of *zu* and *Gunst*, and say *zu meinen Gunsten*. In a similar way, *zu unseren Gunsten*, *zu Stephanies Gunsten*, *zu wessen Gunsten?* are possible. Outside of these fixed phrases, the plural of *Gunst* is no longer used.